# Garbage on NodeMCU REPL

Tags: serial-port, esp8266, nodemcu

First of all, if there is a specific Stack Exchange for this topic please refer me to there.

I installed Micropython in a NodeMCU machine, connected via Tera Term and got garbage. I re-flashed the thing with the `-fm dio` argument (from some forum) and connected via Tera Term and I receive proper characters BUT when I type in I see garbage. And when I execute commands I see garbage too. Weird enough the NUMBERS are ok, just the letters change. It sounds like an ASCII problem not a communication problem...

To make things just weirder I closed the connection and opened it again and from time to time it works as expected. I was able to run the wifi setup (my PC has no wifi so it was useless but I wanted to try something meaningful).

And to make it even funnier Putty (the program I like to use all the time) does not work at all, even when replicating all the settings from Tera Term, it just refuses to connect to the thing.

Any clues?

Comment: I can see t he wifi in my cellphone so the wifi setup and the chip in general seams to function perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Turn off VT100 emulation

I just ran into the same thing, and finally solved it after an hour of banging my head on it. For me numbers would work, as would most special characters and uppercase letters, but lowercase letters would come out as extended ascii symbols.

Comment: can you give detailed instructions on how to do so ?